# How to get params from controller into Sidekiq worker (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have certain actions in my app, and when they occur mailers are sent out.

My actions and mailers and everything work just fine. However, I'm trying to pass this job over a sidekiq worker.

My workers in the app are working fine, but I'm having issues getting my mailers to work via this workers.

Here's my worker

```
class SendMailerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform
    @candidate = Candidate.find(params[:id])
    @candidate.destroy
    TestMailer.send_request()
  end

end
```

And here's my controller

```
  def destroy
    SendMailerWorker.perform_async
  end
```

Yet this set up doesn't work, I'm getting the following error: NameError: undefined local variable or method `params'

So the question is, how do I access params in the worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass your parameters from controller to sidekiq worker

```rb
class SendMailerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(candidate_id)
    @candidate = Candidate.find(candidate_id)
    @candidate.destroy
    TestMailer.send_request()
  end
end
```

```rb
  def destroy
    SendMailerWorker.perform_async(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: is there some reason why     SendMailerWorker.perform_async(params[:id]) doesn't work in the create controller? No ID is being passed to the worker even when I set it up exactly like this.

Comment: by default rails create action does not have id in params. Can you show your `create` action?

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, I was able to figure it out.